# BufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics() sometimes fails after a swap to fullscreen-exclusive mode

Tags: java

I initialize an extended jFrame with a BufferStrategy and so forth, getting a nice animating circle on the screen. I have set a key listener (outside of the update-draw thread) that tells the update-draw thread to change to and from fullscreen exclusive mode, without doing updates or draws until the change is done. This usually works, but on occasion, the draw part of the update-draw thread (update does nothing so far) will have an exception and crash immediately after the switch. Most of the time, it doesn't do this crash, but even this is unacceptable for any program.

Edit: Ah, it's done it again. Notably, though, it actually does it *a few frames after the switch*, and it seems to only do it on the first time running after my computer starts up! Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Buffers have not been created
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.getBackBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.getBackBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.updateInternalBuffers(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.revalidate(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.revalidate(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics(Unknown Source)
at albeyamakiir.lightspeed.LightSpeedFrame.screenUpdate(LightSpeedFrame.java:194)
at albeyamakiir.lightspeed.LightSpeedFrame.run(LightSpeedFrame.java:187)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

End Edit.

I suspect some kind of thread problem, but that's why I told it to change between fullscreen and windowed mode inside the thread, so it wouldn't try to access anything while messing around with displays.

Relevent code:
Extract from the JFrame constructor:

```
initWindow();
if(fullScreen){
    initFullscreen();
}
//Setting graphics buffer strategy
createBufferStrategy(2);//double-buffered
bufferStrategy = getBufferStrategy();
```

Entirety of screenUpdate() (in the update-draw loop):

```
try{
        graphics = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        gameRender(graphics);
        graphics.dispose();
        if(!bufferStrategy.contentsLost()){
            bufferStrategy.show();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Contents Lost");
        }

        //Sync the display on some systems. (I'm told that on Linux, this fixes event queue problems)
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();  
        dontExit = false;
    }
```

gameRender() just draws a random ellipse.

Also:

```
private void initFullscreen(){
    if (!gDevice.isFullScreenSupported()){
        System.out.println("Full-screen exclusive mode not supported");
    }else{
        gDevice.setFullScreenWindow(this);

        validate();

        setDisplayMode(resolutionX, resolutionY, 32);//TODO: set to current resolution instead

        fullScreen = true;
    }
}

private void disableFullscreen(){
    gDevice.setFullScreenWindow(null);

    fullScreen = false;
}
```

Edit: So, I guess my question comes down to; Why is BufferStrategy changing state, what is it changing to, and how can I prevent it? This bug is most peculiar if it really does only show up the first time it runs after startup, and a few frames after changing to fullscreen.

Edit2: Here's the compilable and runnable source: [Zip file]http://www.albeyamakiir.hostzi.com/web_documents/LighSpeedFrame.zip

Comment: "Relevent code:"  Until you resolve the question, how can you know what code is relevant?  I suggest you prepare and post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Because, aside from the main, the constructor (which contains the thread start code), and the code for drawing the ellipse (which is used simply to see if the display prints stuff), this is literally all there is. As I said, the update part does nothing (and is merely a comment to say "put this here"). I'm right at the beginning of my project. As for the SSCCE, the only thing I can cut out is the Window listener. I could post my whole code (after a backup and minor trim), I've never seen that done here, but if that helps...

Comment: "I could post my whole code (after a backup and minor trim).."  Make that a major trim of anything that does not affect the outcome, and you have an SSCCE.  Did you actually *read* the linked article?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Yes I did. I think we're using slightly different meanings of 'minor'. What I mean, is that there's so little to my code that the only trim I can do seems to me to be rather minor, in terms of ratio to what I don't trim, I guess. The page says it must be correct, as in compilable, and there's not much I can remove that will keep it that way. I guess I could remove the ellipse drawing code, but then you would have far less feedback as to what's going on. Either way, I have posted the code now.

Comment: If the code is small enough to be an SSCCE, it is small enough to post directly to the forum.  BTW - your link is reporting "The server is under maintenance, please visit again (a) few hours later."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that you are constructing the GUI on the [*event dispatch thread*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: Sorry it took a while to verify, but this seemed to be my problem. Thanks a lot, especially for the link. (This is why I wish java teachers would explain _why_ we need things. I've been told about it, but only in a "do this and it works" fashion, making it too easy to forget)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is wrong, but I should try to compare your code with the code from [Ivo Wetzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170224/ivo-wetzel) his game engine called [Bonsai](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/Bonsai-Game-Library), written in Java. I used it for some of my games. And it works quite perfectly. But keep in mind, if you would use the engine there were some errors with Mouse Events (depending on fullscreen mode enabled or not), I think the location was incorrect...

And if the problem is the "Exclusive Fullscreen Mode", then you can try to set your frame fullscreen with some tricks:

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setPreferredSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.pack();
```