# Exception in thread (java.lang.IllegalStateException)

Tags: java

I have some sort of problem. Whenever I use `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` (instead of `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`), I get this error message when closing my window:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Buffers have not been created
        at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.getBackBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.getBackBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.updateInternalBuffers(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.revalidate(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.revalidate(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics(Unknown Source)
        at de.hsb.prog2.main.GameLoop.render(GameLoop.java:100)
        at de.hsb.prog2.main.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:151)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

I think it has something to do with this code:

```
private void render()
{
   BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = this.getBufferStrategy();
   if (bufferStrategy == null)
   {
       this.createBufferStrategy(3);
       return;
   }

   Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();

   /////DRAW HERE/////DRAW HERE/////DRAW HERE/////DRAW HERE/////DRAW HERE/////

   if (Debugger.isDebugging())
   {
       g.setColor(Color.orange);
       g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
       objectHandler.render(g);
   }

   /////DRAW HERE/////DRAW HERE/////DRAW HERE/////DRAW HERE/////DRAW HERE/////

   g.dispose();
   bufferStrategy.show();           

}
```

Maybe someone could give me a little hint on how to fix that glitch.

Comment: What is exactly at line 151? or at line 100?

Comment: Line 100 is `Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();`
Line 151 is in the `run()` method. That's where this method is called: `render();`.

Comment: look at this question, it may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234471/bufferstrategy-getdrawgraphics-sometimes-fails-after-a-swap-to-fullscreen-excl